# generated XML through eclipse moxy doesnt contain Root element

Tags: xml, dynamic, jaxb, moxy

I am generating an XML through eclipse MOXY and generated xml doesn't contain Root element, but contains the child elements of Root element.

I am attaching the XSD, code and generated XML. I want the Root element to the part of generated XML.

I am new to Eclipse MOXY. Please help to resolve this issue. 
Thanks in Advance.

XSD:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="example"
 xmlns:myns="example" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">

 <xs:element name="ROOT" type="myns:ROOT" />

 <xs:complexType name="ROOT">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="HEADERDATA" type="myns:HEADERDATA" />
   <xs:element name="PRODUCTS" type="myns:PRODUCTS" />
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>

 <xs:complexType name="PRODUCTS">
  <xs:sequence>
   <!-- Here the min/max tag is for multiple nodes -->
   <xs:element name="PRODUCT" type="myns:PRODUCT" minOccurs="0"
    maxOccurs="unbounded" />
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>

 <xs:complexType name="HEADERDATA">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="SOURCE" type="xs:string" />
   <xs:element name="TARGET" type="xs:string" />
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>

 <xs:complexType name="PRODUCT">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="LASTUPDATED" type="xs:string" />
   <xs:element name="TYPE" type="xs:string" />
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

```
Code :
```

```html
DynamicJAXBContext context = DynamicJAXBContextFactory.createContextFromXSD(xsdInputStream, null, null, null);

DynamicEntity rootEntity = context.newDynamicEntity("ROOT");

DynamicEntity headerDataEntity = context.newDynamicEntity("HEADERDATA");
headerDataEntity.set("source", "source");
headerDataEntity.set("target", "target");

rootEntity.set("HEADERDATA".toLowerCase(), headerDataEntity);


DynamicEntity productsEntity = context.newDynamicEntity("PRODUCTS");
ArrayList productList = new ArrayList();
DynamicEntity productEntity = context.newDynamicEntity("PRODUCT");
   
productEntity.set("lastupdated", "LASTUPDATED");
productEntity.set("type", "type");
productList.add(productEntity);
productsEntity.set("PRODUCT".toLowerCase(), productList);

rootEntity.set("PRODUCTS".toLowerCase(), productsEntity);

JAXBMarshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
marshaller.marshal(rootEntity, System.out);
```

Generated XML :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<HEADERDATA>
   <SOURCE>source</SOURCE>
   <TARGET>target</TARGET>
   <TIMESTAMP>timestamp</TIMESTAMP>
   <XML_VERSION>xml_version</XML_VERSION>
   <XML_NAME>xml_name</XML_NAME>
</HEADERDATA><PRODUCTS>
   <PRODUCT>
      <LASTUPDATED>LASTUPDATED</LASTUPDATED>
      <TYPE>type</TYPE>
      <STYLEID>styleid</STYLEID>
      <PRODUCTID>productid</PRODUCTID>
   </PRODUCT>
</PRODUCTS>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MOXy's dynamic JAXB creates a model that is equivalent to the static one that would be generated.  The `ROOT` entity corresponds to a named complex type.  Just like the static model you need to wrap it in an instance of `JAXBElement` to provide the root element name.

Comment: Hi Blaise, Thank you for your response. I will try this.